# href to name and pass $_GET variable

Tags: php, hyperlink, get

I have to links:

```
<a href="page2.php#anchor1">link 1</a>
<a href="page2.php#anchor2">link 2</a>
```

However, I want to add an extra parameter, link so:

```
<a href="page2.php#form?type=small">link 1</a>
<a href="page2.php#form?type=large">link 2</a>
```

Using php, I need to check if my `$_GET` isset, I need to use it to control an element in my form, like so:

```
<select id="type" name="type">
    <option value="sm" <?php if(isset($_GET['type']) and ($_GET['type'] == "small")) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>Small</option>
    <option value="lg" <?php if(isset($_GET['type']) and ($_GET['type'] == "large")) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>Large</option>
</select>
```

### Important details

- If this is important, I am using my .htaccess to remove the .php extension; could that be a factor?
- Page 2 can be accessed without filling in Page 1, but is not required; If none is set from the $_GET, none should be selected, otherwise, the proper value should be selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query string must come **before** the fragment identifier.

```
page2.php?type=small#form
```